# GA runReport get crashFreeUsersRate by special app

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

According to this page(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema), I could get by 'crashFreeUsersRate' metrics by 'platform' dimension. And it really works well.

However there are multi apps in my project, like *android-A*, *android-B*, *android-C*, *iOS-A*, *iOS-B*, how can I get 'crashFreeUsersRate' metrics with special app?

I tried to use dimension-filter, but it only accepted exist dimension.